# Find Minimum height of cable. Exponential / quadratic functions

Tags: functions

I am struggling to solve the following problem.
A cable between two posts takes the following function: $f(x) = 4e^{-x} +e^x$.
Find the minimum height of the cable.
Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated. It's been a while since I've learnt this...

I was trying to find the point at which x only had one possible value, which would then give me the lowest value of y.

I tried to split it into 2 different functions like $y = 4e^{-x}$ and $y=e^x$ and then try to find where both would give me the same x by doing something like $4e^{-x} =e^x$ but it didn't seem to get me any closer. Something about this seems wrong but that's as far as I've gotten.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)'s a quick guide.

Comment: The standard approach would involve calculating the derivative $f'(x)$ and finding where $f'(x)=0$. Did you try this?

Comment: This is not a parabola. It's not even a hyperbloa (which is the form taken by a hanging cable), because the coefficients of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$ are different.

Comment: By the way, to solve $4e^{-x}=e^{x}$, you can multiply both sides by $e^{x}$ and go from there.

Comment: @TonyK You are right, I was completely mistaken, I will edit my post

Comment: Thank you @Minus One-Twelfth. That is very helpful, I am currently revising how to calculate the derivative. Thank you as well for the tip on how to solve  $4e^−x=e^x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]
Your representation of the question doesn't provide any insight regarding the position of ground, poles, nature of the cable, the place where this phenomenon is taking place. I have provided a possible point of view from where I think you can proceed. My approach has calculus in it but if you are not aware of the methods you can find them in any calculus book discussing maximas and minimas of functions. Thank You.

Comment: This is very helpful, this combined with @Minus One-Twelfth comment about calculating the derivative is enough for me to understand it. My calculus skills are very degraded as I've not used them in many years, but I believe I can follow it well if I spend some more time on it. Many thanks to everyone and apologies if the question lacked detail and clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Well it is a simple question where we have to calculate the minimum height that is the minima of the function $f(x) = 4e^{-x} + e^x$

In order to calculate minima first we calculate derivative of the function

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{d}{dx}4e^{-x} + e^x$

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 4(-x)e^{-x} + xe^x$ (using CHAIN RULE)

$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = -4xe^{-x} + xe^x$

At minima or maxima $\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = 0$

$-4xe^{-x} + xe^x = 0$

$xe^x = 4xe^{-x}$

$e^x = 4e^{-x}$

$\frac{e^x}{e^{-x}}= 4$

$e^{2x}=4$

$\ln(e^{2x})=\ln(4)$

$2x=\ln(4)$

$x=\frac{\ln(4)}{2}$

You can put this value of x in $\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}f(x)$ and you would get a positive value thus a minima exists at $x$

THE MINIMUM VALUE IS

$f(\frac{\ln(4)}{2}) = 4e^{-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}} + e^{\frac{\ln(4)}{2}}$

$f(\frac{\ln(4)}{2}) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{e^{\ln{4}}}} + \sqrt{e^{\ln{4}}}$

$f(\frac{\ln(4)}{2}) = \frac{4}{\sqrt{4}} + \sqrt{4}$

$f(\frac{\ln(4)}{2}) = \frac{4}{2} + 2$

$f(\frac{\ln(4)}{2}) = 2 + 2 = 4$

Therefore 4 units HIGH